# R d3 network graph - stop animation

Tags: r, performance, d3.js

I have plotted a network graph using d3 library but as the number of nodes grow, animation takes a huge performance toll. For analytics, I do not need good UI but something quick

Question: How do I stop the real-time simulation and yet still enable manipulation of the graph?

## Working Code Example

```
require(igraph)
require(networkD3)

# Use igraph to make the graph and find membership
karate <- make_graph("Zachary")
wc <- cluster_walktrap(karate)
members <- membership(wc)

# Convert to object suitable for networkD3
karate_d3 <- igraph_to_networkD3(karate, group = members)

# Create force directed network plot
forceNetwork(Links = karate_d3$links, Nodes = karate_d3$nodes,
             Source = 'source', Target = 'target', NodeID = 'name',
             Group = 'group')
```

Visual Output:

[image]

Comment: Does it have to be javascript-based like D3, or is a static plot fine? There are good tools for static network plots, but those won't work if you need something interactive

Comment: don't run the simulation automatic. stop the sim and call tick() yourself. this will prevent the tick-callback to update the nodes continuously, after 300 tick calls call the tick-callback yourself. Our set a modulo counter in the tick-callback and only update the nodes every 50 calls.

Comment: How to run simulate.tick(300) but it doesnt work. Do you have code sample?

Comment: use a for loop and call sim.tick() 300 times

Comment: This doesnt work. Do you have a working sample of code?